# Rails: Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler, minitest

Here is a trouble: on my remote server command `gem list` shows:

```
some gems
minitest (4.7.5)  
....
```

`bundle show minitest` command shows:

```
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/minitest-4.7.5
```

`bundle show rails` shows the same directory

`bundle -v` - 1.6.2 (the latest version)

But I've an error: `Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

### The steps I've made

- Delete `Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install` again
- Reinstall bundler
- Ruby version 2.1.2

Bundle install output shows `Using minitest (4.7.5)`

Comment: add bundle exec in front of everything.

Comment: @Octopus-Paul It doesn't help

Answer (score 11):

On the remote server run `gem update bundler` and after `bundle install`.

Comment: Reinstall bundler means that I've installed the newest version (updated version 1.6.2)

Comment: This answer seems to be helpful for people but would be greatly improved if it could have a sentence or two explaining why it works and what was wrong in the first place; you seem to be knowledgeable so it would be great if you could help here.

Comment: This error is happening on local machine, not remote server.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe the gems you installed system-wide cause the problem.

You may try `bundle package` locally, and commit the gems generated in `vendor/cache`. Pull it on server, and try `bundle install —local`.

Or, you may just use `bundle install --path=vendor/bundle` on server.

Give it a try, and hope this can help.

Comment: tested all of them but still got the same issue :(