# Could not find 'minitest' (>= 5.1) among 39 total gem(s)

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, cocoapods

Situation:

I am trying to setup Cocoapods.

I'm on OSX 12.2. I have installed Ruby with Homebrew. When I run `gem list` `minitest (5.15.0)` is listed.

Running `pod setup` in terminal fails because it could not find `minitest (>=5.1)` among 39 gems.

I noticed that the directory searched looks to be the OSX system ruby installation at `Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0`; rather than `ruby 3.1.0` (at `/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby`) that I installed with Homebrew.

I assume that what I need to do is point terminal to `ruby 3.1.0`; but, I double checked my .zhsrc file, and it looks to be in order (I learnt about this from reading SO questions and Ruby and Cocoapods setup guides - so I may be very wrong about this).

This is the contents of `.zhsrc`:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

# The next line updates PATH for the Google Cloud SDK.
if [ -f '/Users/sean/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/sean/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/path.zsh.inc'; fi

# The next line enables shell command completion for gcloud.
if [ -f '/Users/sean/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc' ]; then . '/Users/sean/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/completion.zsh.inc'; fi
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"

. /usr/local/opt/asdf/libexec/asdf.sh
```

Can you please help me figure out what I need to do to get `pod setup` to succeed?

Things I have tried:

1. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods `sudo gem install cocoapods`
2. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling cocoapods with homebrew `brew install cocoapods`.
3. Install `bundler` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11885398/is-there-a-fix-for-the-could-not-find-gem-in-any-of-the-sources-error-that-d/11886309) SO suggestion - I tried this and got the error `Could not locate Gemfile`
4. I also ran `sudo gem install minitest -v 5.15.0` - and am still getting the same error. From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70574985/could-not-find-minitest-5-1-among-39-total-gems-gemmissingspecerror) SO question.

Extra Information Below:

If it helps, this is my path:

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/sean/Desktop/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS
```

Here are images of the error:

[image]

[image]

I have looked at these Stackoverflow questions (and many many more) and tried the suggested solutions to no avail:

[Could not find 'minitest' (~> 5.1) among 42 total gem(s) (Gem::MissingSpecError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68466544/could-not-find-minitest-5-1-among-42-total-gems-gemmissingspecerror)

[Could not find 'cocoapods' (>= 0) among N total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361452/could-not-find-cocoapods-0-among-n-total-gems-gemloaderror/45297188)

[How do I install CocoaPods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20755044/how-do-i-install-cocoapods)

[Rails: Could not find minitest-4.7.5 in any of the sources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777277/rails-could-not-find-minitest-4-7-5-in-any-of-the-sources)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved the situation by following [this](https://mac.install.guide/ruby/13.html).

Specifically - I added the following text to the end of the `.zshrc` file:

```
if [ -d "/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin" ]; then
  export PATH=/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH
  export PATH=`gem environment gemdir`/bin:$PATH
fi
```

And then critically - quitting terminal and re-opening it.

Comment: If you're not sure about your ruby path, type `which ruby` in your terminal to get your ruby path and then update the above code with it